# SyntaxError: missing ) in before using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

before` but getting the error in console as SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
     $(".blog-sidebar-form form").before("<p class="blog-sidebar-inform>Dummy Text</p>");
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The syntax highlighting here on SO gives the error away perfectly.

You're nesting double-quotes inside double-quotes without escaping them - it should be something like:

```
.before("<p class=\"blog-sidebar-inform\">Dummy Text</p>")
```

Alternatively, you can change the inner quotes to be single quotes (as pointed out in the comments):

```
.before("<p class='blog-sidebar-inform'>Dummy Text</p>")
```

Comment: +1 To the OP: Get a decent syntax highlighter for your editor. It's worth it!

Comment: Why not just use `'blog-sidebar-inform'` instead of messing around with \.

Comment: I like keeping quoting consistent, not just switching between single and double quotes to keep the parser happy.

Comment: Its easier to stick to one way. I just open my jQuery stuff with `""` and anything inside that with `''`. But that's just me! +1 as this does indeed work.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing `'` to close class name of your paragraph as well as using single quote `' '` to wrap your `class`:

```
$(".blog-sidebar-form form").before("<p class='blog-sidebar-inform'>Dummy Text</p>");
// ------------------------------------------ ^ here ------------ ^ and here ----------
```

Comment: Should they not be `'blog-sidebar-inform'`. As they are opening with `"`

Answer (score 1):

use single and doubble quotes

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
     $(".blog-sidebar-form form").before('<p class="blog-sidebar-inform">Dummy Text</p>');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Fixed.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".blog-sidebar-form form").before("<p class=\"blog-sidebar-inform\">Dummy Text</p>");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have Confused Using quotes,

You must Use Class Name within a quote Like,

```
$(".blog-sidebar-form form").before("<p class='blog-sidebar-inform'>Dummy Text</p>");
```

Or

```
 $(".blog-sidebar-form form").before('<p class="blog-sidebar-inform">Dummy Text</p>');
```

Or

```
$(".blog-sidebar-form form").before("<p class=\"blog-sidebar-inform\">Dummy Text</p>');
```